# How to use the data of cadvisor to calculate the cpu usage and load in Prometheus

Tags: docker, prometheus, cadvisor

when I use the cadvisor to get the information about the cpu in a docker container,I get the information as follow:
[image]

my question is that how to caculate the cpu usage and load,which is the same as Prometheus,through the information returned by cadvisor?how Prometheus caculate the cpu usage?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm that Prometheus uses for `rate()` is a little intricate due to handling of issues like alignment and counter resets as explained in [Counting with Prometheus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67Ulrq6DxwA).

The short version is to subtract first value from the last value, and divide by the time they are over. It's probably easiest to use Prometheus rather than doing this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Below query should return your top 10 containers which are consuming most CPU time:

```
topk(10, sum(irate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id=~".+", id=~"/docker/.*"}[$interval])) by (name)) * 100
```